# What is a continuous image function?

Tags: image-processing

I'm currently studying Zernike Moments, and came across the formula which is:

[image]

and it is said that $f(x,y)$ is a **continuous image function** that is mapped (inner product) onto the Zernike basis function $V_{nm}(p,\theta)dxdy$.

But I'm not entirely sure what does it mean by continuous image function. Is it just a mathematical way of saying images?

Comment: My best guess that an "image function" just a function which represents some image (so it's pretty much an arbitrary function), and that in this particular formula it has to be continuous.